# Why right click on next/link does not show usual menu and 'Open in tab' link?

Tags: next.js

```js
import Link from 'next/link'

return (

<Link
  key={key}
  href={`/dashboard/organizations/${
    selectedOrganizationId ?? organizationId
  }/events/${key}`}
  passHref
  shallow
>
  <li
    className={`${styles.listItem} ${eventId === key ? styles.active : ""}`}
    onClick={() => {
      dispatch(me());
      if (organizationId && eventId) {
        dispatch(getSoldTickets({ organizationId, eventId }));
      }
    }}
    onContextMenu={() => {
      if (isServer()) {
        return;
      }

      const win = window.open(
        `/dashboard/organizations/${organizationId}/events/${key}/`,
        "_blank"
      );
      win && win.focus();
    }}
  >
    {value?.name ?? key}
  </li>
</Link>;
```